# How to get row value from grid when toolbar is clicked in kendo ui mvc grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to get row value from grid when toolbar is clicked in kendo ui mvc grid.
sample View code:

```
<div id="kendoGrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(@<input id='chkPayment' type='checkbox' class='check-box' />).Title("Select");
        columns.Bound(m => m.PaymentDetailDto.InvoiceNumber);
        columns.Bound(m => m.PaymentDetailDto.ModifiedDate).Title("Invoice Date");
    })
    .ToolBar(x => x.Custom().Text("Make Payment").HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnMakePayment" }))

 )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweeps the grid and search for the value it

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        var chkPayment = $(this);
});
```